# Are the permutation or weakening lemmas needed for term substitution?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, types-and-programming-languages

In TAPL book, page 453, Pierce discusses the following lemma:

> $\Gamma , x:S , \Delta \vdash t:T \land \Gamma \vdash s:S \implies \Gamma, \Delta \vdash [x \mapsto s]t:T$

He claims that when $t$ is a variable, we need to use the permutation lemma:

> $\Gamma \vdash t:T \implies \Delta \vdash t:T$ where $\Delta$ is a permutation of an extension of $\Gamma$.

I don't think this should be the case since in this context the (inductive) type rule for variables says:

> $x:T \in \Gamma \implies \Gamma \vdash x:T$

So if I try to prove the original lemma by induction on the typing derivation, I end up with the following subgoals:

$y \neq x \implies \Gamma,x:S,\Delta \vdash y:T  \land \Gamma \vdash s:S\implies \Gamma,\Delta \vdash y:T$

$y = x \implies \Gamma,x:S,\Delta \vdash x:T \land \Gamma \vdash s:S \implies \Gamma,\Delta \vdash s:T$

Here weakening is not applicable since the conclusion context is smaller than the premise's context. Also permutation is not applicable.

I strongly think this is a typo in the solutions and it should say $\lambda$-case...

Comment: Something is wrong with your statement of the lemma. Is there a missing $s$? And what should be the context of the judgement on the right-hand side of the implication? And when you say "So if I do the proof", it is not clear if you do *what* proof of *what* statement precisely?

Comment: @AndrejBauer indeed I completed my question with the right details

Comment: Yes, that sounds likely to me. The case $y \neq x$ requires strengthening (if a variable does not appear anywhere we may delete it from the context), and the case $y = x$ requires uniqueness of typing (if $s : S$ and $s : T$ then $S = T$) and weakening (of $\Gamma \vdash s : S$ to $\Gamma, \Delta \vdash s : T$).